# How to add videos already at vimeo to my channel and showcase

Tags: video, vimeo, channel

I have searched the help at vimeo and looked at lots of menu entries but I can't find the answer to my question:
For a video already uploaded to vimeo, how do I add it to my showcase and to my channel?

I have been able to find out how to upload a video into a channel or into a showcase, but I'm looking for how to add videos already up there to my channel and showcases.

I know that videos are identified just by their unique numbers, and a user can watch my video by going to https://vimeo.com/*number*

Vimeo provides nice ways of listing my videos with thumbnails and descriptions, in a channel for some purposes and in a showcase for other purposes, such as making subsets of my videos.

In channels and showcases they are accessible through links like
https://vimeo.com/channels/*name-or-number*/videos or
https://vimeo.com/showcase/*showcase-number*/video/*number*

Is there a point-and-click way to do what I want?

Or has someone developed an app using the API to make sure that all videos listed in my showcases are also listed in my channel?

Thanks for thinking about my question,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the answer. Kate at Vimeo support showed me.
Here are the steps

1. Log in at Vimeo
2. Hover over your picture and select Collections.
3. At the top-right corner of the image for the channel, click the Settings gear.
4. Click the tab at the top called Videos
5. Click Add More Videos
6. In the list of your videos that appears, click the plus on each video you want to add.
7. Save the changes.

For a showcase, the procedure is similar, except that the tab is called Assets.